# GIT how to handle Untracked files message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

Normally, my workflow to check-in code to github is:

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "description"
git push
```

That has always worked. But now when I commit I get this error:

```
$ git commit -a -m "x"
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   ../db/migrate/20110506232317_add_xxxxxxxx.rb
#   ../lib/xxxxxxxx_job.rb
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

And recommitting with git add . has no effect. Any ideas what's going on here? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try going back a directory first. You seem to be in a subdirectory.